# react native text input disable selection of text entered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-native

I have a Text Input that I am using in React Native and want to disable Text Selection and further options that are show in the image :-

[image]

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872883/react-native-text-input-disable-selection-of-text-entered

Answer (score 3):

You can set attributes editable and selectTextOnFocus to false

Like:

```
<TextInput editable={false} selectTextOnFocus={false} />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `pointerEvents` as `"box-only"` to disable the selection of entered value.

> `<TextInput pointerEvents="box-only" />`.

Answer (score 2):

Just set selection to the end of the text: 
selection={{start: this.state.text.length, end: this.state.text.length}}

Comment: although there is a jumping effect in android, this is the only that works

Answer (score 2):

You can use selection property. And when selection change, set selection prop to end position of your selection.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection: { start: 0, end: 0 },
    };
  }

  onSelectionChange = ({ nativeEvent: { selection, text } }) => {
    this.setState({ selection: { start: selection.end, end: selection.end } });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onSelectionChange={this.onSelectionChange}
        selection={this.state.selection}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have two **Idea**.

1. You can try set in **attribute** `selectTextOnFocus` = "false" `clearTextOnFocus` = "true" from component `TextInput`:
2. You can create a method to remove text with onChangeText if your TextInput is focus.

I hope my idea helping you...